# How to solve duplicate vertex in home range kernel UD - amt package

Tags: r, kernel-density

I'm attempting to run a home range analysis for a nested list (one kernel per nested list) using the amt package. The whole object is a GPS track for an individual, which has been segmented as a previously determined time period into each nested list for which I want a kernel, and then I wish to calculate the overlap between these kernels.

However, I keep running into this error for some kernels:

Error in wk_handle.wk_wkb(wkb, s2_geography_writer(oriented = oriented,  :
Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 48 is degenerate (duplicate vertex)

I've solved this in other work I've done by adding a jitter in the coordinate value so I don't have duplicated coordinates. However, I don't want to do this here as it's a different coordinate system (WGS84 not UTM), different spatial spread of data, and this problem does NOT happen when I run the kernel UD on the whole GPS track (which would include these duplicated coordinates). This leads me to believe that it's a bandwidth issue in the hr_kde() function, but I cannot work out how to change this, especially given that, to my understanding, the bandwidth value is dependent on the sample size of the data used for the kernel and so can't just be assigned the same value throughout. I've looked through the hr_kde_ref() for the kernels and I tried using hcv() from sm package to validate a potential parameter but it kept crashing my program.

The overlaps seem to be calculated fine regardless of the error, so I'm also not sure why this is an issue in obtaining the isopleths and contour lines but not in the overlap between the kernels. Would anyone have a solution to this or explanation for why it happens? Basically I'd just like to be able to plot the contours of the kernels.

**Input data (trck_xyt, ESPG:4326, hab_value runs 1 through 18, t_ in YYYY-MM-DD)**

```
> head(hr)
# A tibble: 6 × 7
     x_    y_ t_                  id     hab_value redlines travel_day
* <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>              <fct>      <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
1 -16.3  16.9 2018-10-05 00:20:53 171025         1        1          2
2 -16.3  16.9 2018-10-05 00:50:18 171025         1        1          2
3 -16.3  16.9 2018-10-05 01:20:18 171025         1        1          2
4 -16.3  16.9 2018-10-05 01:50:19 171025         1        1          2
5 -16.3  16.9 2018-10-05 02:20:22 171025         1        1          2
6 -16.3  16.9 2018-10-05 02:50:20 171025         1        1          2
```

**Code used**

```
trast <- make_trast(hr) # making raster for kernels

hr2 <- hr %>% #nested list for each habitat value
  nest(data = -c(hab_value))  %>% 
  mutate(n = map_int(data, nrow))


hr3 <- hr2  %>% #run hr_kde on 
  mutate( 
    hr_kdedat = map(data, ~hr_kde(., trast = trast, levels = c(0.6, 0.95))) 
  )


for(i in 1:length(hr3$hr_kdedat)){
  
  
  dataf <- hr3$hr_kdedat[[i]] 
  
  # ref <- hr_kde_ref(dataf) ## needs to be changed to hr3$data if used

  plot(dataf) ## error occurs here for i = 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18
  
  hr_iso <- hr_isopleths(dataf)
  
  print(hr_iso)
  
}

overlap_hr <- hr_overlap(hr3$hr_kdedat, type = "vi", 
                         conditional = TRUE, which = 'consecutive', 
                         levels = c(0.6, 0.95))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used st_make_valid and it worked out.

https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/valid.html